# Why is there no current between two capacitors connected in series?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance, voltage, batteries

I want to ask a question about the figure below.
[image]

Why the current does not flow from $-Q$ term to $+Q$ term or from a to b since there is a voltage?

Answer (score 13):

**Short answer**: Potential is defined depending on the choice of a origin (e.g. ground). The positive plate of a capacitor has potential $Q/C$ greater than negative plate of the *same capacitor*. We do not know its potential compared to anything else, unless we know how they are connected in a circuit. Here the points a and b are connected by an ideal conducting wire, hence the *potential difference between them must be zero, so is the current.*

**Detailed answer**: If you connect two uncharged capacitors in series to a battery, there will be a current in the circuit until equilibrium is reached. As current flows, the capacitors will start charging, and there will be a voltage drop along each capacitor.

In equilibrium, the net voltage drop in the two capacitors will be equal to the voltage in the battery.

[image]

**Reason**: Suppose the instantaneous charge in each capacitor at time $t$ is $Q(t)$ (The charges in the two capacitors must be equal - can be proved from law of conservation of charge), and net electrical resistance in the circuit is $IR = dq/dt R$. Then $V = Q(t)/C_1 + Q(t)/C_2 + IR$. Solve this differential equation and take the limit of very large time. You will find that $V = Q(t = \infty)/C_1 + Q(t = \infty)/C_2$.

Hence, the voltage drop of two capacitors is same as the voltage of the battery, $V = V_{C_1} + V_{C_2}$ (As $V_{C_1} = Q/C_1$). But applying Kirchoff's loop law, $V - V_{C_1} - V_{\textrm{between }a\textrm{ and }b} - V_{C_2} = 0$. Comparing these two equations, $V_{\textrm{between }a\textrm{ and }b} = 0$. As there is no voltage, *there will be no current*.

However, if initially $Q_1(t=0)/C_1 + Q_2(t=0)/C_2 \neq V$, there will be a net current flow until the voltage drops along the capacitors balance the voltage of the battery, and then there will be no current.

Consider this analogous situation, where there are batteries instead of capacitors. Will there be a current flow, now that a and b have different polarities? There won't be, as the net voltage between a and b is zero.

[image]

Comment: Ok, But each term has a different charge,  You have positive on term and negative  on the other term, If there is no voltage each term must have same amount and sign of charge.

Comment: Why is there no voltage? If there is no voltage each term must have the same amount and sign of charge but since one term  is negative and the other is positive so there is a voltage . Just tell me why is there no voltage as you say !

Comment: I am not talking about voltage of a capacitor , I am taking about voltage between term a and term b , I am talking about negative term of capacitor one which has negative electric potential (capacitor which is at the top) and positive term of capacitor two which has positive electric potential , These two terms are connected , Why the current doesn't flow ?

Comment: Because voltage between a and b becomes 0 (the reason of which is included in my answer)

Comment: @user8718165 ,Do you mean that at plate a the charges are being attracted by the other positive plate of capacitor one (on the top)

Comment: @MohammadAlshareef I think you're clinging to the notion of there being an absolute zero for charge.  There isn't.  Zero in a circuit like this is defined by convention.  Usually we choose the negative plate of the battery to be zero.  Then the potential at the capacitor terminal connected directly to the negative plate of the battery will also be zero.  The potential at the other terminal of that capacitor will be higher than that, and the potential at the far terminal of the other capacitor will be _even higher_ (and equal to the potential of the positive plate of the battery, in this case).

Comment: May I suggest, as the answer may be more telling for what the OP intended, the following question: One side of a capacitor is marked by electrons, while the other is marked by holes (atoms missing electrons). In this case, the positive holes in one capacitor are electrically connected to the negative electrons in the other, so intuitively one would expect there to be some diffusion between the two, causing some degree of "cancelling each other out". Why don't the electrons rush to fill the holes? Note: Convention actually has the holes rushing to be filled by the electrons, but same behavior.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist Once you start talking about individual charge carriers (electrons and holes) you shouldnt really be talking about conventional current. Both electrons and holes can move and it is wrong to say "by convention the holes move" as you have done. Since this isnt up to convention anymore,  but instead physics.

Answer (score 8):

The charges will remain as they are even after disconnecting the battery(provided you don't connect the other two terminals together). You can imagine the other two plates(say C and D) as producing a uniform E-field and the plates A and B as the opposite faces of a metal block(as they are connected together). The charges are induced on the faces but no current flows as these charges are attracted towards the plates C and D due to Coulomb force of attraction.

[image]

## capacitor fully charged and then disconnected

Now if you look at the electric field lines, you can see that the electric field lines from C to D(not labelled in the image) kinda cancel the electric field lines present in the region between plate A and plate B. Hence you end up with electric field in the region between plate A and plate C (or D)(depends on your consideration) and plate B and plate D(or C)
and no field between A and B and hence the charges within the block (A and B) won't be tempted to move towards each other.

What happens is something like this:

[image]

(This animation is from Wikipedia)

And as we know,
$$E=-\frac{\text dV}{\text dr}=0$$
So the potential difference among the faces $A$ and $B$ inside the block will be zero as the potential is constant.

Answer (score 3):

The voltage *drop* is the same over both capacitors. The voltage *level* is not. For instance, if there is a total voltage of 2 V across the whole circuit, and there is nothing in the circuit other than the capacitors and the voltage source, then both capacitors will have a voltage drop of 1 V. This does not mean that they are "at" one volt, it means that for each capacitor, the *difference* in voltage between their two ends is one volt. So if you start at the negative side of the voltage source and consider this to be "zero" volts (remember, all voltage levels are *relative* to some reference voltage), and go around the circuit, then when you get to the negative side of the first capacitor, you will still be at 0 V (where "zero volts" means "zero volts relative to the negative terminal of the voltage source"). After traversing this capacitor, you will be at 1 V (where "one volt" means "one volt relative to the negative terminal of the voltage source"). When you get to the negative side of the second capacitor, you will still be at 1 V. After you traverse the second capacitor, you will be at 2 V (where "two volts" means "two volts relative to the negative terminal of the voltage source").

Each capacitor has their positive side at one volt higher than their negative side, so for each capacitor, their positive side is at the same voltage *relative to the negative side of that capacitor*. Their positive sides are **not** both the same voltage relative to the voltage source.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the question is about the DC case. There is no current between a and b, as there is no voltage difference. The voltage difference between the plates opposite to a and b, say a' and b', is *canceled out* by the charges on a and b. The plates a and b are connected so form, a single conductor. The charges on a and b are an example of how a conductor cancels out any voltage across it by building up surface charge.

Answer (score 0):

This arrangement can be treated as an electrostatics problem with each of the charged plates producing an electric field.

[image]

Applying superposition shows that the electric field between plates $a$ and $b$ is zero and so is the potential difference between those two plates.